# ¿Guardar DATETIME (GETDATE()) sin milisegundos en SQL desde INSERT en PHP?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Cómo puedo guardar la fecha/hora sin milisegundos en SQL desde sentencia INSERT en PHP con un GETDATE(), les dejo la sentencia que tengo, aclaro que no es preparada:

```
$stmt_save_comment = "INSERT INTO CRM_COM(CREDITO, FECHA_PROM, CR, COMENTARIO, MONTO_PP, AGENTE, FECHA, TELEFONO) VALUES ('$credito', '$fecha_promesa', '$resultado_call', '$comentario', '$monto', '$agente_ejecutivo', GETDATE(), '$telefono')";
```

Ya intente con CAST, CONVERT de diferente maneras así como cambiando el tipo de dato en "desing" en SQL ¿Cómo le puedo hacer? Al principio pensé que era con smalldatetime.

Comment: Intenta con `date_format()`

Comment: ¿Cómo? Lo coloque como date_format(GETDATE(),"Y/m/d H:i:s") pero no deja generar el INSERT

Comment: ¿Qué motor de DB utilizas? ¿Cuál es el tipo de dato del campo?

Comment: Utilizo MS SQL SERVER, es un input date

Comment: En SQL Server el tipo `date` no tiene información más allá de la propia fecha, ni horas, minutos y segundos, así que, nada que hacer para quitar los milisegundos.